# Finding the Minimal Sum of a Logic Function

Tags: logic, boolean-algebra

I have the following logic function for which I was asked to find the minimal sum form.

$F = \bar{A}\bar{B}\bar{C} + \bar{A}B\bar{C} + AB\bar{C}$

Focusing on the second and third terms, I chose to pull out $B$ and then $\bar{C}$, allowing me to eliminate the $A$ terms:

$B(\bar{C}(\bar{A} + A))$

$B(\bar{C}(1))$

This leaves me with the following:

$F = \bar{A}\bar{B}\bar{C} + B\bar{C}$

I don't have a formal background in logic/algebra and so I'm a bit stumped as to what to do now. Assuming I did it right, a logic table for the original function, for which Wolfram Alpha confirms, the solution should be:

$F = \bar{A}\bar{B}\bar{C}$

I believe I'm only one transformation or two away from the answer, but am not sure what identity rule/trick I'm missing to solve this last step (or if I'm just outright wrong). I would appreciate any help with seeing the remaining steps or a potential lapse in my solution logic.

**EDIT**:

---

My claim the final equation above as the desired solution was wrong. I needed to factor out the $\bar{C}$ again and then distribute over the $\bar{B}$ for the inner term, which would yield the answer:

$F = \bar{A}B + \bar{A}\bar{C}$

**Better yet**, look at [M.P.'s](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2459090/331023) answer as it takes the smarter first step of factoring $\bar{C}$ out from all three terms in the initial equation, yielding a much more straightforward solution. Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do one more step:

\begin{align}
&&F ={}& \bar{A}\bar{B}\bar{C} + \bar{A}B\bar{C} + AB\bar{C} \\
\tag{Factorize $\bar{C}$.} \\
&\Leftrightarrow& F ={}& \left(\bar{A}\bar{B} + \bar{A}B + AB\right)\bar{C} \\
\tag{Factorize $B$.} \\
&\Leftrightarrow& F ={}& \left(\bar{A}\bar{B} + \left(\bar{A} + A\right)B\right)\bar{C} \\
\tag{$\bar{A} + A = 1$.} \\
&\Leftrightarrow& F ={}& \left(\bar{A}\bar{B} + B\right)\bar{C} \\
\tag{$\bar{A}\bar{B} + B = \bar{A} + B$.} \\
&\Leftrightarrow& F ={}& \left(\bar{A} + B\right)\bar{C} \\
\tag{Distribute $\bar{C}$.} \\
&\Leftrightarrow& F ={}& \bar{A}\bar{C} + B\bar{C} \text{.}
\end{align}

To obtain $\bar{A}\bar{B} + B = \bar{A} + B$ just note that:

- if $B = 1$ then $\bar{B} = 0$ and $\bar{A}\bar{B} + B = B$
- if $B = 0$ then $\bar{B} = 1$ and $\bar{A}\bar{B} + B = \bar{A}$

Comment: Thank you, your work confirms a second attempt I made earlier today as I realized that $\bar{C}$ was a common factor in each term which gave me your solution above. I will mark this as the answer + kudos for exceptional notation. Also, know that I up-voted your work, it's just not publicly visible.

Answer (score 0):

Some handy laws here are:

**Adjacency**

$PQ+PQ'=P$

**Reduction**

$P+P'Q=P+Q$

**Generalized Reduction**

$PR+P'QR=PR+QR$

Applied to your statement:

$$A'B'C'+A'BC'+ABC' = \text{ (Adjacency)}$$

$$A'C'+ABC' = \text{ (Generalized Reduction)}$$

$$A'C'+BC'$$